# How to apply a regex to the same string containing different words?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a following regex which basically gets string with hyphens:

`/class="(?=\S*[-])([a-zA-Z-]+)/gim`

And the input string is:

```
<div class="hello-world h-123"></div>
<div class="this-is-cool"></div>
```

However, my problem is that in the input string, it only matches `hello-world` but I wanna match `h-123` as well using same regex but separately (groups). Basically, I am trying to build a regex which basically gets all strings that contain dash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Comment: [String.prototype.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

Comment: Why are you using a lookahead?

Comment: Must you use regex for this? There are better methods for getting class names in javascript.

Comment: Are you expecting the final result to have three matches ("hello-world", "h-123", "this-is-cool") or two ("hello-world h-123", "this-is-cool")?

Comment: How are you obtaining those "div" strings? I agree with sean; if this is javascript running in a page with those divs, it would be better to get the classes from the dom elements themselves, rather than pattern-match the html strings. Fully parenthesized because of comment wrapping: `document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(ex => { ex.classList.forEach(c => { console.log( c + ' includes dash? ' + c.includes('-') ); } ); } );` … and the obligatory link to [Don't Parse HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RegExp specify starting with `class="` and contains only letters. Change it to be letters and numbers (I've used `\w` which contains letters, numbers, and underscores) with at least one dash between them:

```js
const regexp = /\w+(-\w+)+/gim
const str = `<div class="hello-world h-123"></div>
<div class="this-is-cool"></div>`

const result = str.match(regexp)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

([\w\s]*[-][\w]*)*

This will look for any string that starts with a alphanumeric character or space, has a hyphen, and is followed by a alphanumeric character.  It does this multiple times to link together hyphenated phrases that may have a space between the first and most recent one.

Comment: This is matching `_   -__    -`

Comment: Correct, OP never specified what all could be in the string.  They just said strings with at least one hyphen in them.